# Newbie question: How do I run a JUnit 3 test on Portable Firefox 3.6 in Selenium RC (1.0.3)?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, unit-tests

I'm pretty new to selenium, and I'm following the Selenium Simplified book examples.

I'm trying to run a simple test that was created in Selenium IDE on Portable Firefox 3.6 and saved as a JUnit 3 test.

My OS is Windows 7 64 bit, and Firefox 4 is the default installation of Firefox (hence the need for portable 3.6, to use the IDE).

The selenium server is already running when the test is run.

The test itself is this:

```
public class MyFirstSeleniumTests extends SeleneseTestCase {
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        setUp("http://www.google.com/", "*chrome");
    }
    public void test_google_for_selenium_rc() throws Exception {
        selenium.open("/");
        selenium.type("q", "selenium rc");
        selenium.click("btnG");
    }
}
```

The output in the server console is this:

```
14:04:44.950 INFO - Command request: getNewBrowserSession[*chrome, http://www.google.com/, ] on session null
14:04:44.961 INFO - creating new remote session
14:04:45.715 INFO - Got result: Failed to start new browser session: java.lang.RuntimeException: Firefox 3 could not be found in the path!
Please add the directory containing ''firefox.exe'' to your PATH environment
variable, or explicitly specify a path to Firefox 3 like this:
*firefox3c:\blah\firefox.exe on session null
```

I tried more variations, but all gave me errors, so let's start here, and see where that goes.

Answer (score 1):

It can't find you firefox path, you will need to modify your path environmental variable to include the firefox.exe location.

To modify your env path do the following:

1. Click Start Menu -> right click on Computer and Select Properties
2. Select Advanced System Settings
3. Click Environmental Variables Under
   System Variables scroll down to
   Path, Select it and Click Edit Add
   the path to your forefox.exe to the
   end with a semi colon in front of it
   (e.g. ;C:\Firefox)
4. Click OK -> OK -> OK and try again.

Comment: Added. I can attest to that since launching firefox from any directory works.  
I still get the same result, though.

Comment: Exactly the same error message?  Very strange, FF4 is not offically supported fully until RC1 so that may be causing you issues.  Does it work using IE?

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with Junit but did you notice error message -

```
Please add the directory containing ''firefox.exe'' to your PATH environment
variable, or explicitly specify a path to Firefox 3 like this:
*firefox3c:\blah\firefox.exe on session null
```

also is it possible for you to downgrade browser to 3.0/3.6 and see if that works?